# Is it possible to create an abstract type and make it compatible for inheritance into child type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, inheritance

Let's say I have an abstract type and function like this.

```
type GenericData = {
    id: string
}

export const recv = ( data: GenericData, properties: Props ): GenericData =>
{
    return {
        id,
        ...properties
    }
}
```

And I want to load this data into more specific types which inherit from the generic type and add to it.

```
type SpecificData = GenericData & {
    name: string,
    phone: number
}

const specific: SpecificData = recv( inputData, props );
```

Now it shows a TypeScript error that `SpecificData` and `GenericData` are not compatible.

How do I create multiple implementations of this generic type when different data is received?

Comment: Is the goal to be able to pass in a GenericData type as the first argument, and then the remaining properties (such as name and phone) as the second argument and get back the specific data type as the return value (eg: `recv({id: "123"}, {name: "x", phone: 123}); // returns SpecificData`)?

Comment: @NickParsons Yes, that is the goal, with various implementations. So `SpecificData` is one implementation and there would also be other implementations, all inheriting `id`, having different properties. Hence why `GenericData` is returned as base type

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for an actual generic function, not just a type whose name starts with "Generic": `recv = <T extends {id: string}>(data: T, …): T => …`

Comment: @Bergi I tried this as it looks interesting, but got this TS error when returning an extra param, even though `T` extends `{ id: string }`. This is the error: `Type '{ id: string; param2: number; }' is not assignable to type 'T'. 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ id: string; param2: number; }'`

Comment: What is `param2`, where does it come from? Please [edit] your question to show the complete code. Also I've probably oversimplified the `T -> T` function, it seems you actually want to merge two inputs, but I haven't yet figured out what exactly you're doing - the goal Nick Parsons mentioned could be solved simply with `Obect.assign` or object spread syntax without any extra `recv` function.